# UNEXPECTED TOKEN ILLEGAL caused by a number in js parameter

Tags: javascript, angularjs, token

I have this code snippet:

```
<input type="file" name="040_featured_4_image" onchange="angular.element(this).scope().uploadFile(this, 040_featured_4_image)" style="display: none">
```

I want to know why this snippet doesn't work, but when I replace the numbers on the parameter `040_featured_4_image` for `forty_featured_four_image`, the function works perfectly

Answer (score 2, accepted):

> ```
> 040_featured_4_image
> ```

Variable names simply can't start with numbers in JavaScript.

Comment: Thank you, I've solved this just adding quotes on that parameter

Answer (score 0):

Quentin has already said that in the answer that you cannot have the variable names that start with number. To add to it as to why it is not possible is by thinking of a very small example:

```
int 040d = 10;
double a = 040d;
```

Now what do you expect the value of a?

Comment: @Marcelo This is a correct answer - you should check for more than just question marks when flagging low quality posts...

Answer (score 0):

Variables can't start with numbers and, the main strange kind that I read is the usage of `angular.element()....`, why not using a simple `<input ng-change="uploadFile($event, ....)">`

Comment: Thank you!! That code is for 2 months ago (I was an Angular rookie) and I did an strange mix of jQuery + Angular, and the only solution I found (time issues too) was that one. I'm not specially proud about it :(